# How do i connect to a postrgresql database instance using Amazon Web Services in java code?

Tags: java, sql, database, postgresql, amazon-web-services

I recently made an account using Amazon Web Services - hoping to get access to a 24/7 database in postgresql. However, there is little documentation as to how to connect to a postgresql database instance using straight java code. So my question is, how would I connect to my made  database?? Please be specific. some .getConnection code would be helpful. AND AGAIN. I WANT TO USE JAVA CODE. No extensions or toolkits.

heres some connection code:

```
try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
       //Uncomment the following line if using a keystore.
       props.setProperty("ssl", "true");  
       props.setProperty("user", "BruceWayne");
       props.setProperty("password", "password");
       connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:postgresql://batcomputer.cu2oezud659w.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432",props);

    } catch (SQLException e) {

        System.out.println("Connection Failed! Check output console");
        e.printStackTrace();
        return;

    }
```

my guess is that the problem is at the line where "connection" is.

and here is the error at the terminal:

```
1291-121-25:SQLGUI student$ javac -cp postgresql2.jar:. JDBCExample.java
1291-121-25:SQLGUI student$ java -cp postgresql2.jar:. JDBCExample
-------- PostgreSQL JDBC Connection Testing ------------
PostgreSQL JDBC Driver Registered!
Connection Failed! Check output console
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:postgresql://batcomputer.cu2oezud659w.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com:5432
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:596)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:187)
    at JDBCExample.main(JDBCExample.java:38)
```

any help is highly appreciated!!!

Comment: You would need postgresql JDBC driver. Once you have that it should work like any other JDBC connection. Link to the drive site: http://jdbc.postgresql.org/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot easily connect to PostgreSQL (or any other database) without "extensions or toolkits". Specifically, the only sane way to do it is to [use JDBC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/jdbc/index.html). The JDBC interfaces themselves are part of Java, but connecting to individual databases requires database-specific *drivers*.

For PostgreSQL, that's [PgJDBC](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/).

So you really need to:

- [Read the JDBC tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/); and
- [Read the PgJDBC documentation](http://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/documentation.html)

The JDBC tutorial explains how to use JDBC. The PgJDBC documentation explains the details of the PostgreSQL specific bits, like the JDBC URL you should use to connect to PostgreSQL. It contains example code too.

After you've ensured that PgJDBC is on your classpath, connecting (without doing anything with the connection) is as simple as:

```
public void donothing() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException
{
    Class.forName("org.postgresql.Driver");
    String url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost/test?user=fred&password=secret&ssl=true";
    Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
    // Do stuff here
    conn.close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, for AWS (Amazon Web Services) specifically, what would you suggest? - especially regarding the "url" part??

Comment: For instance, I already have the conn and Driver down and ready - but I still get errors for trying to establish a connection with AWS from the terminal?

Comment: AWS EC2 isn't special, you connect with the hostname, port, etc just like anything else. If you mean AWS RDS PostgreSQL, it tells you the hostname and port to use. Really, it's just like any other server. I suggest posting a new question with the appropriate details - particularly the exact text of the error message and the relevant code.